# Counting the total number of files which meet a certain criterion in Python

Tags: python, list, operating-system

I am writing a code which scans all the folders and calculates averages of all the files which meet the criterion: `min(numbers) <= 0.5 * max(numbers)`. However, I also want to do a total count of all folders which satisfy the criterion. I present the current and expected output.

```
import os

NFILES = 10 #Scans -1 named files

values = [[] for _ in range(NFILES)]
Folder_name='220 nodes_seed896_var5_100stepsize_0.45initial'


for i in range(NFILES):
    filepath = rf"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder_name}\{i}\len_J.txt"
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath) as data:
            lines = data.readlines()
            numbers = [int(line.strip()) for line in lines if line.strip().isdigit()]
            if (min(numbers) <= 0.5 * max(numbers)):
                values[i].extend(numbers)
                print("File numbers which meet the criterion =",i)


valid_values = [v for v in values if v]  # Remove empty lists



for t in zip(*valid_values):
    with open(rf"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder_name}\Averaged.txt", 'a') as f:
        #writer = csv.writer(f)   
        #print("J =",len(J[0])) 
        f.writelines('\n')
        # if i < len(J[0]) - 1 and len(J[0][t + 1]) >= len(J[0][t]):
        #     f.writelines('\n')
        #     f.write(str(J[0]))
        
        f.write(str(sum(t) // len(t)))
```

The current output is

```
File numbers which meet the criterion = 1
File numbers which meet the criterion = 2
File numbers which meet the criterion = 7
File numbers which meet the criterion = 8
```

The expected output is

```
File numbers which meet the criterion = 1
File numbers which meet the criterion = 2
File numbers which meet the criterion = 7
File numbers which meet the criterion = 8

Total number of files which meet the criterion = 4
```

Comment: The question says you want to count folders, but your expected output is the number of files. Which is it?

Comment: Isn't `len(valid_values)` the number you want?

Comment: Why do you fill your `values` list with empty lists, and then filter out the ones that weren't extended? Initialize it as an empty list, and `append()` to it in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count=0
for i in range(NFILES):
filepath = rf"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder_name}\{i}\len_J.txt"
if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as data:
        lines = data.readlines()
        numbers = [int(line.strip()) for line in lines if line.strip().isdigit()]
        if (min(numbers) <= 0.5 * max(numbers)):
            values[i].extend(numbers)
            print("File numbers which meet the criterion =",i)
            count+=1
print('Total number of files which meet the criterion =',count)
```

Here, I've used the variable 'count' to keep track of the number of files meeting the criterion.